# Application fails to start after building using cx_Freeze on OSX

Tags: python, python-3.x, build, cx-freeze

I'm trying to build a simple app on OSX using cx_Freeze. The build using setup.py seems to go fine - it builds a .dmg and .app for my application, along with all of the source files. However, when I try to run the .app, it crashes immediately, saying "My_App quit unexpectedly". Frustratingly, I don't see any decipherable error codes I can track down.

I have stripped down the app into a very simple example. Below are my main python file and my setup file.

**my_app.py**

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title("Welcome to My_App")
root.geometry('350x200')
root.mainloop()
```

**setup.py**

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need fine tuning.
build_exe_options = {"packages": [], "excludes": []}

# base="Win32GUI" should be used only for Windows GUI app
base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

setup(
    name = "My_GUI",
    version = "1.0",
    description = "My GUI application!",
    options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
    executables = [Executable("my_app.py", base=base)]
)
```

I have built an .exe on windows before, and when startup fails on windows, I at least get a traceback error message that I can track down. On OSX, it doesn't appear to do the same thing.

What's going wrong? How can I get more information on why my app is failing to start up? Below are images of my build and the error I'm getting on startup.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ok turns out if I run the file from terminal, it outputs an actual error code. From there, I was able to track down that I did not have zlib installed. I was getting error

```
zipimport.ZipImportError: can't decompress data; zlib not available
```

What ultimately solved it for me was reading through this thread

https://github.com/jiansoung/issues-list/issues/13